# PHP/JSON decode multi array in php

Tags: php, json

Hy Guys,

i have problem with decode json data in php.

There is json input:

```
{
    "name":" Test",
    "data":[
        [
            1388617200,
            35
        ],
        [
            1388703600,
            35.2
        ],
        [
            1388962800,
            35.15
        ],
        [
            1389049200,
            34.95
        ],
        [
            1389135600,
            35.1
        ],
        [
            1389222000,
            35.1
        ]
    ]
}
```

How to parsing field data array , these data need to be saved in MySQL DB

Many thanks for help

Comment: i am newbee sory . I have problem with this part  "data":[ [ 1388617200, 35 ], [ 1388703600, 35.2 ], [ 1388962800, 35.15 ], [ 1389049200, 34.95 ], [ 1389135600, 35.1 ], [ 1389222000, 35.1 ] ]

Comment: @Hunt3r OK, but what specific problem? Dump out the data as `print_r` to see its structure.

Comment: `json_decode()`? after that it's just a normal php data structure, and you access the stuff in it like you would any OTHER php data structure.

Comment: My problem is to create a PHP script to read (prepare data for DB) the field DATA.  Example is here ont his page http://spacenet.cz/macek/pokus.php

Comment: Did you try `$result = json_decode($json_input)`. Then you can access `$result->data`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's like:

```
$d = json_decode($yourArray["data"]);
foreach($d as $x) {
    $timestamp = $x[0];
    $whatever  = $x[1];
    mysql_query("insert into yourTable set
        field1='$timestamp',
        field2='$whatever'
    ");
 }
```

Approximately.
This example is not to be used in production of course, I'm not even sure it doesn't have typos or something - but the principle should be clear.  If this looks messy and you can't implement it in your project, *(really-really no offense but)* I suggest you to keep reading PHP docs and learn how its data structures work.

Comment: thanks you i try it , and tell you

Comment: Many thanks for FAST HELP

Comment: (Oh how I love downvoters without a comment. Doesn't truly matter, it's just annoying.)

Comment: I'm a downvoter. Sorry for the late comment. You're encouraging sql injection and using the `mysql_*` which doesn't even _exist_ anymore in the current PHP version.

Comment: As I said it should not be used in production, it's merely the principle. I could have written "sqlInsert" which never even existed.  The problem was not how you insert rows but how you walk an array of arrays.  This is a beginners' task.  I understand your point tho.

Answer (score 0):

just use json_decode:

```
$var = json_decode($JsonString);
```

You can access the field `data` with `$var -> data`

Answer (score 0):

this script working.

```
$var = json_decode($json);
$dat_name = $var -> name;
$dat_array = $var -> data;
echo $dat_name;
$d = ($dat_array);
foreach($d as $x) {
   $timestamp = $x[0];
   $whatever  = $x[1];
}
```